# How to insert the polygon and checking if a passed polygon is inside it in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, geolocation, polygon

Can I check if a polygon is inside another polygon in mysql query? What will be the query to get all the polygons which contains the passed polygon in the where string?

After googling, I found a query:-

```
SELECT *, AsText(poly) FROM geos 
 WHERE Contains(
 GeomFromText('POLYGON((42.000497 -109.050149, 
 41.002380 -102.051881, 
 39.993237 -102.041959, 
 38.999037 -109.045220, 
 42.000497 -109.050149))'), poly );
```

I am not sure what it is doing basically? So what will the query to insert the polygon and checking if a passed polygon is inside it?

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a polygon like this:

```
SET @g1 = 'POLYGON ((
    //your points of polygon here
))';

INSERT INTO geos set poly=ST_GeomFromText(@g1);
```

And if you want to check another g2 if it contains g1:

```
SELECT * FROM geos WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_GeomFromText(@g2), poly);
```